# Send stdout over TCP connection

Tags: c, redirect, server, client, stdout

I have a client and server program where the server is a shell

I need to redirect the output of the shell to the client

As I understand, after I dup() to stdout and run execve, the output should be sent over the stream and printed on the client side

Here's my client code...

```
while(1){
  printf("rrsh> ");
  Fgets(buf, MAXLINE, stdin);
  int nul = p3parseline(buf, argv);
  if (!strcmp(argv[0], "quit"))
    break;
  Rio_writen(clientfd, buf, strlen(buf));
  Rio_readlineb(&rio, buf, MAXLINE);
  if (!strcmp(buf, "Command not allowed\n")){
    strcpy(buf, "Cannot execute '");
    strcat(buf, argv[0]);
    strcat(buf, "' on this server\n");
    Fputs(buf, stdout);
  }
  else if (!strcmp(buf, "Command approved\n")){
    printf("WOOHOO\n");
  }
}
```

...and here's the server code...

```
  while((n = Rio_readlineb(&rio, buf, MAXLINE)) != 0){ //loop until connection has been terminated
    printf("server received %zu Byte(s)\n", n);
    bg = p3parseline(buf, argv);
    temp = strcat(argv[0], "\n");

    //check if the command is allowed
    file = Fopen("rrshcommands.txt", "r");
    while (Fgets(command, MAXLINE, file) != NULL){
      if (!strcmp(temp, command)){
        flag = 1;
        strcpy(buf, "Command approved\n");
        break;
      }
    }

    strtok(argv[0], "\n");

    if (flag == 0){ //case where the command is allowed
      strcpy(buf, "Command not allowed\n");
      Rio_writen(connfd, buf, strlen(buf));
    }
    else{
      if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {   /* Child runs user job */
        Dup2(connfd, STDOUT_FILENO);
        Close(connfd);
        if (execve(argv[0], argv, environ) < 0) {
          printf("%s: Command not found.", argv[0]);
          exit(0);
        }
      }
      /* Parent waits for foreground job to terminate */
      if (!bg) {
        int status;
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
          unix_error("waitfg: waitpid error");
        Rio_writen(connfd, buf, strlen(buf)); /*this writes "Command approved to the client*/
      }
    }
  }
```

Take note that the shell only allows certain commands that are specified in the rrshcommands.txt file

Stop here if you think you can figure out, below is debugging info

What's weird is the execution and debugging are giving me two different results

Here's the output of the client during execution...

```
Kendalls-MacBook-Pro:P4 kendallweihe$ ./rrsh-client 127.0.0.1 1024
Username: kendallweihe
Password: password
rrsh> /bin/ls
rrsh> /bin
```

Note that it doesn't print out either Cannot execute blah command on this server OR Command approved

But when I debug, it prints the statements...

```
   47           Fputs(buf, stdout);
   48         }
   49         else if (!strcmp(buf, "Command approved\n")){
-> 50           printf("WOOHOO\n");
   51         }
   52       }
   53     }
(lldb) n
WOOHOO
```

AND

```
   46           strcat(buf, "' on this server\n");
-> 47           Fputs(buf, stdout);
   48         }
   49         else if (!strcmp(buf, "Command approved\n")){
   50           printf("WOOHOO\n");
(lldb) n
Cannot execute '/bin' on this server
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you *do* close the `rrshcommands.txt` file somewhere? Because it looks like you don't which means you have a resource leak. And why open and read it over and over again, why not open and read it into memory once, and then just compare the received command to the in-memory buffer?

Comment: Also remember that `fgets` (the *standard* [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function) leaves the newline in the buffer it reads, so comparing strings might not always work as you expect.

Comment: As for your problem, I'm not quite sure what it is? Can you please elaborate? But you send the output of the command you execute *before* you send `"Command approved\n"`, so the neither string comparison in the client should return zero, which of course could be a problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but sending the output before would be fine because the connection is a stream, the command approved is there just so I can print command was allowed -- probably unnecessary though

Comment: @JoachimPileborg notice temp gets "\n" concatenated to it

Comment: @JoachimPileborg btw, closing the text file resolved the cannot execute blah command error message

Comment: But in the client (at least the part you show us) you send the command to the server, you read it's response and compare the response from the server with the approved/not-approved messages. The `"Command approved\n"` string will be *last* in the buffer you receive, not first. And even if it were first, the `strcmp` tries to match the *complete* strings, you should probably use `strncmp` instead.